# Using GitLabRunner to execute GUI tests on windows with permanent active user session

Tags: windows, user-interface, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i'm having issues to get a permanent active user-session on my virtual machine to execute gui tests developed with the functional testing tool Ranorex Studio via GitLab-Runner (Windows / Shell). The testsuite is based on a .NET solution which is built via MSBuild.exe and the output (bin/debug/*.exe) will be executed with some parameters via command line.

Procedure:

- Start gitlab-runner via PowerShell as administrator with "gitlab-runner run" command
- Make some changes in GitLab-Repository to start the pipeline via .yml-File
- Ranorex test-project is built successfully and is starting the GUI-tests
- In the first run the user session is active and the tests are going to be executed and interacting with the GUI, but when i try to trigger the pipeline again for further runs, the user-session turns to false and there is no interaction with the GUI (black sceenshots in test-report).

Already did:

- Screensaver disabled
- StandBy-Mode disabled
- User-Access-Control on lowest setting
- Lock-Screen disabled
- Secure-Login disabeld
- Remote connections enabeld
- Ports openend
- Keep Session open via .batch-File, when closing RDP-connection
- GitLab-Runner Service => Log on with respective AD-User (equipped with admin-rights)
- AD-User is alway logged in on virtual machine

With Jenkins (Master / Slave configuration) everything works fine

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Does your Ranorex process close down properly with an exit code?  Does the Application Under Test also close down properly at the end?  I am assuming something has locked - you could try a bit of Powershell to close the processes before a test run.  One thing I had to do was keep the screen on - using a utility like 'Caffeine'.

Comment: Hello, 

the issue is aleady fixed.

It is important that GitLab Runner is not started as windows service because then there would no communication with the UI of the VM be possible.

Following command resolved the issue:

    "gitlab-runner.exe run"

With that command the GitLab runner will not be executed as windows service.

It can also help to set the GitLab runner in windows services to 'manual' so that the service will never be executed manually.